# DNS transfer: where is my "www"?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am in a middle of a DNS transfer. (Lets say my url is 'example.com')

The `example.com` URL points to the new IP address, but `www.example.com` still takes me to the old IP, what can I do about this?

Comment: 'example.com' is a reserved domain for the purpose of, well, using an example

Comment: Edited and cleaned up his post a little to make it more clear.

Comment: try: dig +trace www.domain.com

Answer (score 7):

Did you reduce your TTL to a shorter time before the transfer? If not, then your A record for `www` may still be cached by resolvers and there's nothing you can do to expire the cache sooner.

For more information, see [How to Speed Up DNS Propagation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130822093915/http://www.technologytricks.com/speed-up-dns-propagation/).

Comment: +1 for informative link.  the only thing i'll add to that is that some DNS servers are broken or deliberately misconfigured to ignore TTLs and will always cache records for a long time.  there is nothing at all that can be done about that.

Answer (score 3):

It can take days to propagate around the Internet.

Try from a different computer using a different ISP or the tools at http://www.dnsstuff.com/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's still in the cache. Assuming windows, in cmd.exe enter the following:

```
   ipconfig /flushdns
```

and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check that your name server actually works properly. Under Linux use

dig @your.name.server www.example.com

and check that it does what you want it to do. Under Windows, use nslookup and once you're at the prompt (start it in interactive mode) change the name server to your name server, then enter www. example.com and check the results.

If these tests come back OK, then it's simply a matter of waiting (as pointed out by other answers, in the future it's a good idea to keep your TTL short if you're planning to make changes).

Comment: +1 for keeping TTL short when planning changes.  it's always best to set the TTL very low (say, 5 minutes) a few days before re-delegating DNS (where "a few days" is significantly larger than your current TTL).  that way, the propagation is very quick...and if something goes wrong, you can quickly change back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your dns lookup servers on your computer to [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com), to get a second point of view if caching is the problem. You'd set the DNS settings on your own computer to 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220.

I've a couple times had it where my ISPs hadn't updated but the OpenDNS servers had.

Answer (score 0):

You never did anything during testing like...I don't know...alter a host file or manually point or alias that name on the web server to point at an IP, or did something to an internal DNS cache somewhere?

What does a dig for your domain show, and nslookup?

Answer (score 0):

just for clarity's sake, www is a different record than the domain's root A record...www must be specifically declared in the zone file.

Sorry if that's stating the obvious, but the OP doesn't sound like that's the case.

An example:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
blahblah.com             IN SOA  ns3.foobar.com. techcontact.foobar.com. (
                                2009060401 ; serial
                                86400      ; refresh (1 day)
                                10800      ; retry (3 hours)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
                        NS      ns2.foobar.com.
                        NS      ns3.foobar.com.
                        A       1.2.3.4
$ORIGIN blahblah.com.
www                     CNAME   blahblah.com.
```